# Spring Boot 3 @SpringBootTest-annotated tests does not execute gateway auto-configuration

Tags: spring-boot-test, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-3

I have a very simple test:

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"instance.role=GATEWAY", "instance.name=test-instance", "debug=true"})
@TestPropertySource(locations = {"classpath:application.yaml"})
class GatewayWiringTest {

    @Autowired
    private MySpringBootApplication application;

    @Test
    void gatewayConfigLoads() {
        assertThat(application).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

Since my application starts with different bean configurations, depending on the role it gets assigned, I use such tests to test that each configuration is loadable.

It did run without problems with Spring Boot 2.7. It doesn't run with Spring Boot 3.0 (obviously, after having updated Java to version 17 too, not just the spring/spring boot dependencies). The root cause of the error is:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

I have traced the problem to the class `GatewayAutoConfiguration` from the spring cloud gateway server dependency not being evaluated for loading - this is the autoconfiguration class that should provide the missing bean.

I have also verified that the class *is* on the classpath when the test is executed, by running the test with `mvn -X` and looking at the classpath. The problem isn't that one of the two conditions for loading the class evaluates to false, the problem is that those conditions never get evaluated in the first place - running the test with `--debug` generated the conditions evaluation report, and the class `GatewayAutoConfiguration` doesn't appear in either of the two lists - matched and unmatched conditions.

Why doesn't it get processed? What do I need to do differently with Spring Boot 3.0 compared to Spring Boot 2.7, in this regard specifically?

Comment: Hi @user625488 were you able to resolve this issue as i am facing similar issue in which after i upgrade spring-boot from 2.7.18 to version 3.0.0 and the spring cloud dependencies version from 2021.0.9 to 2022.0.0 the integration test start to fail. I am using WireMock for test and the application context fails to loadup during the test after upgrading to spring-boot 3.

Comment: I worked around the issue by having `spring.main.lazy-initialization=false` in the application configuration. That makes the test less relevant, because it doesn't provide a guarantee as strong that with lazy loading all beans still load correctly as running the test with lazy loading enabled would, but it got me past the issue.